# I get Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [api_console_project_id] when trying to publish app

Tags: google-apps-script, manifest

I get his error when trying to save this manifest file:

Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [api_console_project_id]

My manifest file is

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "api_console_project_id":"my-project-ID"
}
```

I've enabled and configured the google store SDK

Comment: editing in Google App Script service? app script manifest "appsscript.json" seems different from standalone manifest.json

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps buy my standalone manifests look something like this.

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",    
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Exchange",
  "description": "Link to...",
  "version": "2.3",
  "icons": {
  "128": "128.png"
},
  "container" : ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],  
  "api_console_project_id": "NOT_EASY_TO_FIND_PROJECT_ID",
  "app": {
  "urls": [
  "https://script.google.com/a/macros/ilavietnam.edu.vn/s/PUBLISHED_ID/exec"
],
  "launch": {
  "web_url": "https://script.google.com/a/macros/ilavietnam.edu.vn/s/AKfycbx7Xj0EWjLyTDpzi44dFRw0zePAhvn-Qn4OpwaLpH5SjUNKaWA/exec"
}
},
  "permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "notifications"
]
}
```

Also the Market Place SDK API needs to be turned on.

[image]

Comment: It is turned on

Comment: It is turned on